# Making Windows paths work in RSync through Cygwin, when getting paths from Python script

Tags: python, cygwin, rsync

I am trying to make a Python GUI app that interfaces with RSync through Cygwin. I have gotten the subprocess done but RSync errors out due to the paths not being Unix compatible.

I know that paths should be formatted as `/cygdrive/<drive letter>/<path>/<to>/<file or directory>/` in order to work, and that is what's holding me back. I do not know a way to make a path fetched with `filedialog` formatted like that, and I couldn't find something online with my attempts to search this up.

I've tried to to append `/cygdrive/` with `os.path.join` (perhaps not what the command is supposed to do) infront of the path string but that did nothing, when I expected it to format the strings as `/cygdrive/<drive letter>/<path>/<to>/<file or directory>`

I've also tried using `os.path.relpath`, `os.path.normpath` and passing those directly to the subprocess command as `subprocess.run(["rsync", "-a" , os.path.relpath(<Source Path>)], os.path.relpath(<Destination Path>))` but also nothing (also probably wrong commands but that's what I had in mind)

Current code stands like this

```
import customtkinter
from tkinter import filedialog as fdiag
from tkinter import messagebox as mbox
import subprocess
import os

# Vars
global fdiagSrc, fdiagDest
fdiagDest = ''
fdiagSrc = ''

#Prepare Cygwin stuff
os.chdir(b"C:/cygwin64/bin/")
print(os.getcwd()) #Was checking if it was changing in the directory just in case

# Declare button stuff here first
def srcSel(): # Open a file dialog for Source directory selection, and assign that directory as a string  to a global var
    global fdiagSrc
    fdiagSrc = fdiag.askdirectory()
    while (len(fdiagSrc) == 0): # Show a warning in case user pressed "Cancel" or the close button on the dialog window and re-open the dialog
        mbox.showwarning("Warning!", "You did not select any directory for source!")
        fdiagSrc = fdiag.askdirectory()
    mbox.showinfo("Src", fdiagSrc)

def destSel(): # Open a file dialog for Destination directory selection, and assign that directory as a string  to a global var
    global fdiagDest
    fdiagDest = fdiag.askdirectory() # Show a warning in case user pressed "Cancel" or the close button on the dialog window and re-open the dialog
    while (len(fdiagDest) == 0):
        mbox.showwarning("Warning!", "You did not select any directory for destination!")
        fdiagDest = fdiag.askdirectory()
    mbox.showinfo("Dest", fdiagDest)

def GoToSendDir():
    if (len(fdiagDest) == 0) or (len(fdiagSrc) == 0): # Show a warning in case they didn't select any directories
        mbox.showwarning("Warning!", "You did not set any directories for Source and/or Destination! Please do that.")
    else: #Proceed to transfer/mirror/clone whatever it is called
        print(os.path.normpath(fdiagSrc)) # Checking the path if it is formatted properly..
        subprocess.run(["rsync", " -v -a ",os.path.normpath(fdiagSrc), os.path.normpath(fdiagDest)])

[.... misc GUI stuff not related to issue ....]
```

Comment: `os.path.splitdrive` helps to handle the drive letter part. `str.replace` can convert backslashes to forward slashes.

Comment: @MichaelButscher that appears to have done most of the heavy lifting for this. Thank you! Do post this as a solution. I just had to replace the "C:" path pointer to "c" so that Cygwin could understand it. Now I just have to fix my subprocess string because the `rsync` command is failing due to the paths not being split.

Comment: If you convert to using the `PathLib` module instead of the `os.path` module, you may find the necessary path manipulations to be easier. PathLib can work with abstract paths as well as concrete paths, i.e. os-neutral vs os-specific paths. (Also, just as an aside, if you can use the cygwin Python instead of the windows Python, but you will need to turn on X-windows in cygwin to use a GUI with cygwin Python.)